# Suspecting pear fireblight but not sure.Any help appreciated

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, pear

We have several fruit trees in our garden but having fruiting problem only with a pear tree.It is maybe 8 years old, every year has fantastic blossom but after the flowers turn into tiny fruits they suddenly wilt.I suspected it was due to fireblight but when looking on pictures proposed by several gardening sites describing fireblight I noticed leaves on the branch tips also wilt which is not happenning in our case.Because of the issue we get  just symbolic number of pear fruits every year simply saying not more than 5-6 fruits....

[image]

Comment: Which part of the world are you in?

Comment: @Bamboo East mediterrian, north croatian coast....

Comment: When I grew pears the most practical action was to cut and remove ( burn as possible ) any affected parts.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Here,only flowers are to be removed....all other parts are healthy.